# Передача данных между методами

Tags: java

хотел бы разъяснить для себя довольно простой вопрос
К примеру, в методе main я хочу ввести переменную а со сканера
Затем передать а в метод increment
В этом методе a++
Затем передать а в main
И вывести а

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: В чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Хотел бы именно разъяснить как передать переменную в другой метод, потом получить ее обратно и вывести)

Answer (score 1):

```
AtomicInteger a = 123;
increment(a);

private static void increment(AtomicInteger ai) {
  ai.incrementAndGet(); // or ai.set(ai.intValue() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Передача переменной в метод

```
public int getAndReturnVariable(int yourVariable) {
// делаем что надо с переменной yourVariable
// .....
return yourVariable;
}
```

Получение переменной из метода

```
int yourVariableNew = getAndReturnVariable(yourVariable);
```

Вывод переменной

```
System.out.print(yourVariableNew);
```